# What is the way to represent factor variables in scikit-learn while using Random Forests?

Tags: scikit-learn, text-mining, random-forest

I am solving a classification problem using Random Forests. For that I have decided to use Python library scikit-learn. But I am new to both Random Forest algorithm and this tool. My data contains many factor variables. I googled for that and found out that it's not right to give numerical values to factor variables like we do in linear regression, as it will treat it as continuous variable and give wrong result. But I could not find anything about how to deal with factor variables in scikit-learn. Please tell me the options to use or point me to some document where I can get it.

Comment: You say that "it's not right to give numerical values to factor variables like we do in linear regression, as it will treat it as continuous variable". You absolutely should not do this for linear regression. Random Forest can actually deal with this pretty well, but linear regression will definitely deal with your factors as continuous variables and give a very, very wrong result.

The OneHotEncoder and get_dummies methods below are a must for linear/logistic regression, but may be optional for Random Forest.

Answer (score 11):

If you are using a pandas data frame to you can easily use the get_dummies function to accomplish this. Here's an example:

```python
import pandas as pd

my_data = [['a','b'],['b','a'],['c','b'],['d','a'],['a','c']]
df = pd.DataFrame(my_data, columns = ['var1','var2'])
dummy_ranks = pd.get_dummies(df['var1'], prefix = 'var1_')
print dummy_ranks

   var1__a  var1__b  var1__c  var1__d
0        1        0        0        0
1        0        1        0        0
2        0        0        1        0
3        0        0        0        1
4        1        0        0        0

[5 rows x 4 columns]
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use the sklearn's [OneHotEncoder](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html). What it does is create a new variable for each distinct value in your categorical integer feature.

So for example if you have variable `var` with values `[10, 25, 30]`, it will create three new variables (i.e. matrix with 3 columns), essentially with variables `var_10`, `var_25` and `var_30` with values `[1, 0, 0]`, `[0, 1, 0]` and `[0, 0, 1]` respectively.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But this does not solve  my problem as I don't have integer features. The features I am talking about takes many different strings (words) or sometimes an array of strings.
Btw I am trying to categorize text data using random forests. The data in question is the review given by different users about a product.

Comment: See the documentation about [text feature extraction](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#text-feature-extraction).

Comment: Alternatively, use the Pandas (http://pandas.pydata.org/) library which has a get_dummies function that can convert arbitrarily typed columns into factor variables.